# Invertible Adjoint matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How do you show that if the adjoint of a matrix $A$, adj$A$, is invertible then $A$ is invertible?

I know how to prove the opposite, but I can't figure out how to prove it.

Eden Segal

Comment: What do you know about the product of a matrix and its adjoint?

Comment: Eden --- say something --- anything --- let us know you're still with us. You've had an answer up for a couple of days now, and a lengthy string of comments; what do you reckon?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean adjoint:
$\det A^* = \det {\overline{A^T}} = \overline{\det A^T} = \overline {\det A}$.

If you mean adjugate:
$A \operatorname{adj}(A) = \operatorname{adj}(A) A= (\det A) I$.

Comment: This does not agree with the way I use the word adjoint.

Comment: This does agree with my use of both the words "adjoint" and "adjugate", but of course: the adjoint has such a simple expression only if we're using an orthonormal basis...

Comment: @Don, the definition of adjoint with which I am familiar makes no reference to a basis.

Comment: @Gerry If $V, W$ are linear spaces equipped with bilinear forms $γ_V \colon V × V → K$ and $γ_W \colon W × W → K$ to some base field, you can define a map $g \colon W → V$ to be _adjoint_ to a linear map $f \colon V → W$ if for all $v ∈ V, w ∈ W$: $γ_W(f(v),w) = γ_V(v,g(w))$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, neither does the one I'm familiar with. I just remarked that the adjoint is the transpose of the conjugate *when* we're using an orthonormal basis.

Comment: @K.Stm., I doubt that's the kind of adjoint OP has in mind. The question is posed in terms of matrices and invertibility of matrices, with no hint of interest in bilinear forms and linear maps.

Comment: @Don, an orthonormal basis for *what*? A matrix is a matrix is a matrix, I don't see what its adjoint has to do with a basis for, well, anything.

Comment: In my book, *Adjoint* matrix or transformation wrt to a given matrix of transf. is wrt an inner product (or, more in general, if we have a bilinear form..etc.). I don't know what *adjoint* could mean without this.

Comment: @Don, I've posted an answer that was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 1):

[Too many characters for a comment]

There seems to be some dispute as to the definition of the adjoint of a matrix. Given a square matrix with entries $a_{ij}$, the *minor* of entry $a_{ij}$ is denoted $M_{ij}$ and is defined to be the determinant of the submatrix remaining after the $i$th row and $j$th column are deleted from $A$; the *cofactor* of entry $a_{ij}$ is defined by $C_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}M_{ij}$; the *adjoint* of $A$ is the matrix whose $ij$-entry is $C_{ji}$.

These definitions are taken from Anton, Elementary Linear Algebra, 8th edition. The same definition is given in Noble and Daniel, Applied Linear Algebra, 3rd edition, and in Wedderburn, Lectures on Matrices.

eden --- is this the definition you are using for the adjoint?

Comment: What you've described there, @Gerry, is what I used to call "classical adjoint" and it is nowadays also known as "adjugate", most probably to distinguish between these two very different things with identical names. Google it.

Comment: @Don, I see what you mean. But Maple still uses Adjoint(A) in its LinearAlgebra package to calculate the matrix I define above. In any event, only eden knows which adjoint the question is about --- and eden is maintaining radio silence.